Error al ejecutar jar "A Java Exception has occurred"
tengo este problema en el cual me arroja ese mensaje, tenia otro código mas complejo el cual me arrojaba la misma excepción, por lo que realice este código sencillo pero de igual forma me arroja la excepción al ejecutar el jar. Tengo el JDK y el JRE las ultimas versiones, busque soluciones pero todas son lo mismo, instalar o reinstalar lo hice y no funciona.


package exemplo;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World");

    }

}

##(El primer codigo con el mismo error)
package ejemplo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Clase1 {



public static void main(String[ ] arg) throws IOException {

      System.out.println ("Empezamos el programa :)");
      System.out.println ("Por favor introduzca una el saldo de la factura");
      String entradaTeclado = "";
      try (Scanner entradaEscaner = new Scanner (System.in)) {
        entradaTeclado = entradaEscaner.nextLine (); 
      }
      System.out.println ("Entrada recibida por teclado es: \"" + entradaTeclado +"\"");


      Path fileName = Path.of("C:\\Users\\Ingreso_Facturas\\Downloads\\"+entradaTeclado+".xml");      
      String str = Files.readString(fileName);
      str = str.replace("QtyItem", "QtyItem1");
      str = str.replace("QtyRef", "QtyItem");
      str = str.replace("QtyItem1", "QtyRef");
      System.out.println(str);

      
      
      File archivo = new File("C:/Users/Ingreso_Facturas/Downloads/"+entradaTeclado+".xml"); // este es el archivo que insertaras caracteres      
      FileWriter escribir = new FileWriter(archivo);
      String texto = str;
      for(int i=0; i<texto.length();i++)
      escribir.write(texto.charAt(i));
      escribir.close(); 


  }

}

Datos de mi instalación
java 22.0.1 2024-04-16 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22.0.1+8-16) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0.1+8-16, mixed mode, sharing)

java 22.0.1 2024-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22.0.1+8-16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0.1+8-16, mixed mode, sharing)

Necesitas poner la traza completa, este error generalmente se asocia con usar alguna palabra reservada en el lugar equivocado, en este caso estoy casi seguro que es porque tu clase se llama "main", intenta cambiarlo y nos cuentas

Nop, no era eso, nose a que te refieres con la traza completa ni como hacerlo pero de sintaxis no fue lo intente con este codigo y el resultado fue igual, lo exporto como jar ejecutable, lo intento abrir y arroja el mismo mensaje.

El error ocurre solo con el jar?? no ocurre con el programa dentro de la ide.???

Para nada, de echo el fichero solo desde la cmd se ejecuta bien, desde el ide igual sin errores.

debe ser un problema en el enpaquetado, o un problema en las versiones de tu JDK y JRE, con que estas trabajando, ant, gradle o maven?

Ninguna de esas, la verdad solo quería crear un ejecutable pero investigare acerca de lo que nombraste y veré que pasa.

si fuera un problema de enpaquetado, intenta esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10132818/19194551

Veo que estás usando Eclipse, es importante, veas en la consola que error se está provocando, el diálogo indica que tienes uno o varios errores en tu código.
Existen varios detalles al leer y crear el código, te sugiero corregirlos de esta forma:
package ejemplo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Clase1 {



public static void main(String[ ] arg) throws IOException {

      System.out.println ("Empezamos el programa :)");
      System.out.println ("Por favor introduzca una el saldo de la factura");
      String entradaTeclado = "";
      try (Scanner entradaEscaner = new Scanner (System.in)) {
        entradaTeclado = entradaEscaner.nextLine (); 
      }
      System.out.println ("Entrada recibida por teclado es: \"" + entradaTeclado +"\"");


      Path fileName = Path.of("C:\\Users\\Ingreso_Facturas\\Downloads\\"+entradaTeclado+".xml");      
      String str = Files.readString(fileName);
      str = str.replace("QtyItem", "QtyItem1");
      str = str.replace("QtyRef", "QtyItem");
      str = str.replace("QtyItem1", "QtyRef");
      System.out.println(str);      
      
      File archivo = new File("C:/Users/Ingreso_Facturas/Downloads/"+entradaTeclado+".xml"); // este es el archivo que insertaras caracteres      
        try (FileWriter escribir = new FileWriter(archivo)) {
            String texto = str;
            for(int i=0; i<texto.length();i++)
                escribir.write(texto.charAt(i));
        }       
    }
 

  }

}


Realicé la instalación de Maven además de utilizarlo pero se repitió la misma historia el archivo .jar no ejecuta por si solo sin embargo desde la CMD si lo hace por lo cual de momento solo encontré esta solución ejecutar el archivo por medio de un archivo .bat creado en la misma carpeta del ejecutable.
El archivo contiene:
start javaw -jar project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Luego es simplemente ejecutar el .bat y el programa estaría corriendo.
